# What geographical features facilitate amber fossilization?

Tags: fossils, paleogeography

[image]
<sub>Image source: [Wikimedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Spider_in_amber_%281%29.jpg/296px-Spider_in_amber_%281%29.jpg).</sub>

There seems to be a few places in the world where [amber](https://www.britannica.com/science/amber) (fossilized tree resin) can be found in large quantities:

> Amber can be found in many places around the world including Northern Myanmar (Burma), Mexico and the Dominican Republic, but 90% of the worlds supply comes from the Baltic Region.
>   <sub>[Amber for Sale](https://www.fossilera.com/fossils-for-sale/amber) (commercial site)</sub>

I'm curious about what aspects of these sites give rise to so much amber, unlike most places in the world.

**Question**: What geographical features facilitate amber fossilization?

I would guess there were certain resin-producing trees in those areas, while in other areas the trees didn't produce (a sufficient amount of) resin.  However, there seems to be more to the story: given that [exposed amber degrades](https://list-of-birthstones.com/Amber.html), the amber would need to be prevented from degrading.

Comment: [What type of depositional environment preserved amber?
One depositional environment for amber is marginal marine.](http://academic.emporia.edu/abersusa/whatis.htm)